# How Can I get all the analyzer which my elasticsearch support?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I Get All analyzer which my elasticsearch support?

Is there any API for find out that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no a way to retrieve all analyzers that Elasticsearch
supports via the API. (I do think you may want to open a github issue to add
that feature however).

The list of supported analyzers can be found in the [Elasticsearch reference
documentation on analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html).